# linux ifconfig doesn't return an IP address

Tags: linux, ip, ifconfig

I want to know the IP adress of my linux (virtual machine)
but when i enter ifconfig it doesn't return an IP adress.

Normally it should be between "link encap" and "up broadcast" but it's not..
where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Does your VM have internet connection? It seems to me that it doesn't have the interface configured.

Quick try, write in a shell "dhclient eth0".

If it still doesn't have IP, post the output of ifconfig.

Comment: dhclient eth0 runs for a while but eventually returns nothing.. 
ifup eth0 returns:
" failed; no link present. check cable" 
so i assume i don't have internet on the virtual machine but don't know where to trouble shoot